# weakly holomorphic modular forms with a simple pole at $\infty$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, meromorphic-functions

Let $l$ be a prime. Suppose that $M_0^{!}(\Gamma_0(l))$ donote the space of weakly holomorphic modular forms of weight $0$ for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(l)$. Does there exist a $f\in M_0^{!}(\Gamma_0(l))$ such that $f$ just has a simple pole at $\infty$? Here I require that $f$ is holomorphic on the upper half plane and $0$.

It's known that if $l\in \{2, 3, 5, 7, 13\}$, the answer is yes and we can construct such $f$ with Dedekind eta function. What if $l=11$ or $l>13$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No such $f$ exists, except for the five specific prime levels $2,3,5,7,13$ you describe.

Any such form would give an isomorphism of Riemann surfaces between $X_0(p)$ and $\mathbf{P}^1$. So it cannot exist if $X_0(p)$ has genus $> 0$, which holds for all $p$ except these five.

EDIT. You asked about the minimal order of pole of a (nonzero) weakly holomorphic function. This is equivalent to asking for the smallest $n$ such that $\ell(n\infty) > 1$, where $\ell(D)$ is the vector space of functions whose poles are bounded by the divisor $D$. The Riemann-Roch theorem tells us that this is bounded above by $1 + g$ but it could be smaller; the exact value is not purely determined by the genus (unless $g = 0$ or $g = 1$), since it depends on whether $\infty$ is a Weierstrass point, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point.

EDIT (II). According to [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-22/issue-1/On-the-Weierstrass-points-of-X_0N/10.1215/ijm/1256048830.full), Atkin proved in 1973 that if $\ell$ is prime, $\infty$ is never a Weierstrass point of $X_0(\ell)$. So the minimal order of pole of a non-constant modular function of level $\Gamma_0(\ell)$, holomorphic away from $\infty$, is exactly $g + 1$ where $g$ is the genus.

Comment: Thank you so much! May I know the minimal order of pole at infinity for each $l$?

Comment: Does the minimal order have anything to do with the genus of $X_0(l)$ or something else?

Comment: @W.Ma There has been work on the question of whether $\infty$ is a Weierstrass point on $X_0(N)$, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.03400) by Im, Jeon and Kim. I think William Stein built a table for $N$ up to a certain bound but I cannot find the reference.

Comment: Sorry for more questions.. Now that $g+1$ is the minimal order, what will the other orders be like? I mean, if $f$ is a non-constant modular function for $\Gamma_0(l)$, holomorphic away from $\infty$, denote $m$ to be its order of pole at $\infty$. Does $g+1$ have to divide $m$?

Comment: Your question is already answered in the Wikipedia article I linked to.

Comment: Sorry for the foolish question.. Get it. There was something wrong with my internet so that I couldn't get to the Wikipdia.. Thank you again for your help and patience.